# how to paste int into require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am writing discord bot, and I have a database (in JSON) with a prefix of guilds.

```
{
   "guilds":{
      "721463236070866955":{
         "prefix":"!"
      }
   }
}
```

Then, I require a database by:

```js
const db = require("./database/json");
```

After getting guild id by:

```js
gld = new discord.Guild(client, data);
gid = gld.id();
```

I need to get prefix from JSON, but how?

Comment: `db.guilds[gid].prefix`, though your want to check exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.guilds[gid].prefix` would give you the prefix of the guild

However, using a JSON database is poor practice. You would be better using a db. Even something as simple as sql would suffice. (npm package better-sqlite3 is a pretty good one)

This would solve problems like

- having to delete the cache and re-require the file
- having to copy the entire contents into cache just to make simple changes to the file

Also there is a chance that your requesting the prefix before the guild has been added to the db so you will need to check for that

Simply `if (!db.guilds[gid].prefix) { ....doesn't exist }`